# Count number of character occurrences in a string in PHP without use available function

Tags: php, arrays, string

Sorry if this question already exists.
I have a question can you help me.
Only use `strlen` function and array. Can you make programming count number of character occurrences in a string with PHP (Character not repeat). Similar to create a new `array_count_values` function that available in php.
Eg:

```
$input = 'lorem lis pum';
Output: 
l appeared 2 times;
o appeared 1 times;
r appeared 1 times;
...
```

This is my code when using available function `array_count_values` and it's worked.

```
$a = str_split($str, 1);
foreach (array_count_values($a) as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === ' ') {
        $key = '_';
    }
    echo $key.'appeared '.$value.' times<br>';
}
```

Thanks for read.

Comment: I'm curios to know why you need to create a paradigm that is already exist ? does there another approach you want to achieve ? and for that you need to create a new method for that?

Comment: @hassan I want to learn more about this. and maybe I will make a new method in the future. :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it. I'm sure there's even more concise ways to do it.

```
$input = 'lorem lis pum';

for( $i = 0, $ilen = strlen( $input ), $result = array(); $i < $ilen; $i++ ) {
  $chr = $input[ $i ];
  // substituting the space with an underscore is not actually necessary
  if( $chr === ' ' ) {
    $chr = '_';
  }
  $result[ $chr ] = isset( $result[ $chr ] ) ? $result[ $chr ] + 1 : 1;
}

var_dump( $result );
```

<sup>You can [view this example online](https://3v4l.org/TaBBJ).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, hope its help :)

```
<?php
$input = 'lorem lis pum';

function outputs($input)
{
    $input = str_replace(' ', '', $input);

    $characters = str_split($input);

    $outputs = [];

    foreach ($characters as $char)
    {
        if(!isset($outputs[$char])){
            $outputs[$char] = 1;
        } else {
            $outputs[$char] += 1;
        }
    }

    foreach ($outputs as $char => $number)
    {
        echo $char . ' appeared ' . $number . ' times;<br />';
    }
}

outputs($input);
?>
```

or simple version:

```
<?php
$input = 'lorem lis pum';

function outputs($input)
{
    //suggest remove all spaces first
    $input = str_replace(' ', '', $input);

    $chars = str_split($input);

    foreach (array_count_values($chars) as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key. ' appeared '.$value.' times<br>';
    }
}

outputs($input);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use function [count_chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

```
foreach (count_chars($str, 1) as $key => $value) {
    echo chr($key).' appeared '.$value.' times<br>';
}
```

Comment: thanks @Timur but I don't want to use availiable function.