# I am trying to get number of occurrences of a charaters in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Below is the code i tried, where count is showing improper.
Please help me to get where i am missing the logic.
I am attaching the code which i have tried so far.
PS Note:- I am not intended to use more built in function of php and so I created function for string length.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$string = "ssddk";

function checkString($addinString, &$stringBK) {
    if (empty(count($stringBK))) {
        $stringBK[] = $addinString;
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($stringBK as $key => $val) {
        if ($addinString == $val) {
             return true;
        }
    }

    $stringBK[] = $addinString;
    return false;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < checkstrlength($string); $i++) {
    $count = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < checkstrlength($string); $j++) {
        if ($string[$i] == $string[$j]) {
            if (checkString($string[$i], $stringBK)) {
                continue 2;
            }

            $count++;
            echo "Column => " . $string[$j] . " for count" .$count . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

function checkstrlength($string) {
    $count = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $string[$i] != ""; $i++) {
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

### It gives below output ,

```
Column => s for count1
Column => d for count1
Column => k for count1
```

### I am expecting it as ,

```
Column => s for count 2
Column => d for count 2
Column => k for count 1
```

Comment: _I am not intended to use any built in function of php and so I created function for string length._ I can see empty() and count() functions already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108529/count-number-of-character-occurrences-in-a-string-in-php-without-use-available-f may be of help

Comment: I am editing the post thanks :)

Comment: What does `checkString()` do by the way?

Comment: it check if the character is already found so not to count it again for next row iteration.

Comment: "_I am not intended to use more built in function of php_" Is this for learning purposes? Because PHP has [count_chars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php). Which "built in function of php" are you allowed to use?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there a couple of things to look at here.

- The `checkstrlength()` has the below loop.

  ```
   for ($i = 0; $string[$i] != ""; $i++) {
  ```

  Formally speaking, we usually look at `\0` terminating character in the string to terminate our loop. But in PHP, everything is a string. So, `\0` is now a string to match on rather than a character match. Better, we do an `isset` check to stop our loop. So, code would look like:

  ```
  for ($i = 0; isset($string[$i]); $i++) {
  ```
- Second is your not caching the result which you got from `checkstrlength()`. Do it. Also, you can start the inner loop from `$i` itself. There is no need to go from start again. So, for loop would look like:

  ```
  $length = checkstrlength($string);

  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
     for ($j = $i; $j < $length; $j++) {
  ```
- Third is that there is no need of `empty` and `count` checks in `checkString`.  *This also reduces inbuilt function calls*. You can simply loop over and `return true` if found. If not found, we are adding it anyway. So it would look like:

  ```
   function checkString($addinString, &$stringBK) {
     foreach ($stringBK as $key => $val) {
       if ($addinString == $val) {
           return true;
       }
     }
     $stringBK[] = $addinString;
     return false;
   }
  ```
- Now, in your nested loop, you add it to `$stringBK` outside of the inner loop, because there is no point in checking with the inner loop when chars match. This is because if some character was visited, why initialize the inner loop at all. Just have a check above and continue the search and count. Also note that you are having `echo` statements inside the inner loop which doesn't make sense because we haven't finished the count yet. Let's do and print it outside of the inner loop at the end. Snippet as follows:

  ```
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
     $count = 0;
     if (checkString($string[$i], $stringBK)) {
        continue;
     }
     for ($j = $i; $j < $length; $j++) {
        if ($string[$i] == $string[$j]) {
           $count++;
        }
     }

    echo "Column => " . $string[$i] . " for count : " .$count,PHP_EOL;
  }
  ```

**Final Code Demo:** https://3v4l.org/4dpST

Comment: @Sam Glad I could help :) If you were looking for a faster approach, [see this](https://3v4l.org/2oeYb)